# dart variables aren't equal to what they're set to be in the constructor of an object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this class called branch:

```
class Branch {
  String id;
  String businessName;
  String businessAddress;
  String businessPhone;
  int status;

  Branch({
    businessName = "unknown",
    businessAddress = "unknown",
    businessPhone = "unknown",
    id = "unknown",
    status = -1,
  });
```

Then I have this simple stateful widget:

```
class PageMain extends StatefulWidget {

  PageMain({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageMainState createState() => _PageMainState();
}

class _PageMainState extends State<PageMain> {
  bool _isInitalized = false;    

  void _initializeOnFirstBuild(){
    if(!_isInitialized) {
      Branch testBranch = new Branch(businessName: "test");
      print(testBranch.businessName);
      _isInitialized = true;
    }
  }

  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _initializeOnFirstBuild();
  }
}
```

when trying to print the name of the business or any other variable that is stored and set in the constructer it returns null. (returns returns "null" instead of "test")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialisation in constructor is wrong. You need to use `this` keyword.

```dart
Branch({
    this.businessName = "unknown",
    this.businessAddress = "unknown",
    this.businessPhone = "unknown",
    this.id = "unknown",
    this.status = -1,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use **didChangeDependencies**.

According to the documentation:

> Called when a dependency of this State object changes.

**And**:

> This method is also called immediately after initState. It is safe to
> call BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType from this method.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html

However, I would not right your business logic in this method, because this method is not guaranteed to always get called, unless any dependencies within the widget change. If nothing changes, then this method does not get called.

There are first off, two problems. First you are not overriding the method in the **_PageMainState** widget. If you are not overriding the method, then how is **_initializeOnFirstBuild** supposed to get called if only the base logic runs?
So, add an **@override** attribute on top of the **didChangeDependencies** method.

```
@override 
void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _initializeOnFirstBuild();
  }
```

Then it should work.

Second, please instead write your initialisation of the **Branch** class directly in the **initState** method, like this:

```
 class PageMain extends StatefulWidget {
    
      PageMain({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _PageMainState createState() => _PageMainState();
    }
    
    class _PageMainState extends State<PageMain> {
      bool _isInitalized = false;    
    
      void _initializeOnFirstBuild(){
        if(!_isInitialized) {
          Branch testBranch = new Branch(businessName: "test");
          print(testBranch.businessName);
          _isInitialized = true;
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initializeOnFirstBuild();
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answering quickly.
This is only a part of a larger file so I forgot to copy the "@override".
The reason for using the ```didChangeDependencies()``` is that I have a provider in this initialization function and I need access to the context.

Comment: If this works for you, then please don't forget to mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: actually the problem was that I forgot to put the "this." key word before each variable I set in the constructor.